# Jquery - [objectHTMLCollection] to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get my id values into a function that runs when a keyup event happens. I want the user to select number of names they want to use as the select the number of names my div populates and each input box has an id. On each input created the search text box will run my function. Everytime I type a letter in the search box that was automatically created I get [objectHTMLCollection] I need my function to grab the id (name) as a string so that it runs its checks here is my function:

```
function autocomplet_names_loop(para_names,para_list) {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword_val = para_names;
    alert(keyword_val);
}
```

where para_names,para_leist parameters must have string name of my id.
Below is the loop when user selects a number

```
for(var i=0;i<=selected_num; i++)
   {

       var var_names_id = "";
       var_names_id = "names_id_1";
       var var_names_list_id = "";

    inputfields += "<div style='width:320px;float:left;'><div class='label_div' style='width:50px;'>Search : </div><div class='input_container' style='width:250px;'><input type='text' id='names_id_"+i+"' onkeyup='autocomplet_names_loop("+var_names_id+","+var_names_list_id+")' style='width:150px;'>&nbsp;<img src='img/add-sales.png' onClick='#' width='14' height='14' style='cursor:pointer;width:14px;height:14px;'><ul id='names_list_id_"+i+"' ></ul></div><div class='label_div' style='width:50px;'>Name : </div><div class='input_container' style='width:250px;'><input type='text' id='names_"+i+"' style='width:200px;' readonly><input type='hidden' id='names_id_"+i+"'></div></div><div style='width:250px;float:left;'><div class='input_container' style='width:200px;'>&nbsp;</div><div class='input_container' style='width:200px;'><span style='font-size:11px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>R</span><input type='text' id='names_val_"+i+"' style='width:150px;' ></div></div><div style='width:300px;float:left;'> <div class='input_container' style='width:300px;'>&nbsp;</div><div class='input_container' style='width:300px;'><span style='font-size:11px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>% VALUE</span><input type='text' id='names_val_percentage_"+i+"' style='width:100px;background-color:#CCC;' readonly></div></div>";  

   }
   fillbox.append(inputfields);        
});
```

I have created jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/saiyan10133/9mqgsbkL/13/

Select a number then in the search box will appear I want it to display the id value created.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection ?

Comment: Had a look at the link you sent. Now it says : Currently HTMLCollections does not recognize purely numeric IDs. Does that mean if my id contains a number it won't work. That is why I needed it to be a string.

Comment: Have you run your Fiddle? It's littered with script errors explaining what's going wrong: `Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplet_agent_loop is not defined`

Comment: @TapuwaSimonMundeta The issue is because of not wrapping the evaluated value with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to make one change in the onkeyup event

```
onkeyup='autocomplet_agent_loop(\""+var_agent_id+"\","+var_agent_list_id+")'
```

You've to enclose the variable `var_agent_id` with in `""` so that it will be replaced with string. In your case, it's replaced by string which is `agent_id_1`but which will act as variable during evaluation.

During run time it will look like this:

```
autocomplet_agent_loop(agent_id_1,123123)
```

It means the function will start looking for variable `agent_id_1` and it won't be available. So once you wrap the variable then it will become

```
autocomplet_agent_loop("agent_id_1",123123)
```

Which will behave as string.

Similarly for the `autocomplet_agent_loop`.

**[Working fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9mqgsbkL/16/)**

Comment: Thanks it works now I want to alert the agent_id_1.val(); based on what ever I had put in my search box,$(''+keyword_val+'').val(); throws undefined

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/9mqgsbkL/17/ I've made two changes. Made ID to be dynamic before it was static agent_id_1.

Comment: Thanks for the response, mine is still saying undefined could you kindly point out ? I appreciate the assistance. I have added the following var keyword = $("#"+para_agent).val(); alert(keyword); it throws the undefined on the first id the second it works fine.

Comment: The change was in this line as well: var_agent_id = "agent_id_"+i; before it was hardcoded to agent_id_1. Now i made it to be dynamic

Comment: Thanks @mohamedrias it worked. Now I have to figure out why when I select a name it goes to the last input field. I have ticked this question as resolved I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87251/discussion-between-tapuwa-simon-mundeta-and-mohamedrias).